# Memory bad acces: Questions with releases, protocols and delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a little question with memory management is iOS...

Well I define a own view that have one protocol. In other class, I create an instance of the other class, I add the view to other view and then, I try to release de instance. The problem appear when I call to the method of the protocol because I receive a BAD_ACCS error. It is something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    Class1 *c1 = [[Class1 alloc]init];
    [c1 setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:c1.view];
    [c1 release];
}

- (void)methodOfProtocolClass1 {
    NSLog(@"c1 method called")
}
```

The Class1 have one button and when I press it I call to methodOfProtoclClass1 and makes the error. Does anyone know how to release this object?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to release c1, instead you must retain it! **addSubview** does not retain c1 instance, it retains only its view! If you refer to c1 later you will get a bad access

Comment: Yes I know, but if you make the same with one UIButton it works: You can alloc one button, then you can add it to your view and then release it. Why not with a own view? :S  (Thanks for the answer!)

Comment: because you are not passing the whole object (c1), but "a piece" of it (c1.view)

Answer (score 1):

You are overreleasing c1 here...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    Class1 *c1 = [[Class1 alloc]init]; //allocates Class1 instance with +1 ref count

    [c1 setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addSubview:c1.view];
    [c1 release]; //releases c1, ref count goes to 0 and the memory is reclaimed later
}
```

therefore you get bad access, you instance of c1 is gone and not valid by the end of your viewDidLoad method

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And I say the same that in the previous answer. If you can do it with a UIButton, why not with a own class?

Comment: You are adding c1s view in there, not c1, if you do a button which is a UIView, then when you add it its retained, here you are adding Class1s view, which retains its view property but not the Class1 Instnace